# Scrape background-image with puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, background-image, puppeteer

Can someone please explain how I can scrape the background image from a webpage using Puppeteer? The image is within the class image-background, but nothing is stored in it. the jpg URL is in the

element.style { background-image: url('https://xxxxx.jpg')

How do I scrape the URL 'https://xxxxx.jpg'?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us with what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

You will need [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to retrieve the CSS properties of the element.

**Example:**

- **webpage:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/
- **selector:** `.home-masthead`
- **bg image:** element.style { background-image: url('https://developer.mozilla.org/static/img/home-masthead-background.37a14f03abee.svg')

You can test it out in Chrome DevTools how to achieve the desired result.

`getComputedStyle($('.home-masthead')).backgroundImage`

[Get the right property with chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXdRV.jpg)

Then the puppeteer script can be something like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function getBackgroundImage() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/')

    const backgroundImage = await page.evaluate(el => window.getComputedStyle(el).backgroundImage, await page.$('.home-masthead'))
    console.log(backgroundImage)

    await browser.close()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
getBackgroundImage()
```

**Result:**

`url("https://developer.mozilla.org/static/img/home-masthead-background.37a14f03abee.svg")`

After this you just need to clean the string a bit, I would do it with regex `match()` so you can get content between two patterns, for example:

```js
const backgroundImageCleaned = backgroundImage.match(/url\("(.*)"/)[1]
```

Of course in your case the substring method works as well as this CSS property will have the same format all the time.

Comment: Thank you David, sorry I am new at this, how do you remove the URL and "" () with regex? I think replace() wont take out the URL string and I dont want to remove the letters URL as there may be some in the href.

Comment: By using it in a `match` you can get content between two patterns, for example:

`const backgroundImageCleaned = backgroundImage.match(/url\("(.*)"/)[1]`

Of course in your case the substring method works as well as this CSS property will have the same format all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about regex but got it done by this way.

```
 const backgroundImage = await page.evaluate(el => window.getComputedStyle(el).backgroundImage, await page.$('.home-masthead'))

 const backgroundImageUrl = backgroundImage.substring(5,backgroundImage.length-2);
```